# Spring HttpClientErrorException and RestClientException getting request URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http, resttemplate

I have more then 1 http call in try-catch block, exmaple:

```
try {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    ResponseEntity<String> sendGet = http.sendGet(someUrl1, httpHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<String> sendPost = http.sendPost(someUrl2, httpHeaders);                 
                    
}catch(HttpClientErrorException e) {

   //print call url here someUrl1/someUrl2
   printException(e);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    printException(e);
    //general e             
}

//Print exception
public void printException(Exception e){
     //log URL here
}
```

I want to print the failed URL when I catch the exception but I did not find `HttpClientErrorException` or `RestClientException` property that I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT for general case:**

I don't think you should use `HttpClientErrorException` for getting url, you know the URL before calling each request, so my suggestion:

Create a generic send method which receive post method, URL and headers parameters

Call your method for each request and it will also handle exceptions based on current URL

**For simple case describe in question**:

You can split to 2 try and catch blocks for each request

Or add a boolean ( or currentUrl String variable)

```
boolean isFirstRequestFinished = false;
```

Set it to true after first request  and check in catch block

```
if (isFirstRequestFinished) {
```

Comment: I know I can do that but I want a generic solution if possible, let's say I have 100 calls in my try block.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I would refactor to send method which receive post method, URL and headers, method will also handle exceptions generic based on current URL

Comment: I know I can do all of that, I just want to know how to retrieve the URL from exception object, we send the exception object to another method that prints it and I prefer not change that method signature by adding URL string.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas your method will call inner generic method, so no change in method signature

Comment: That could work, still I want to understand how can I get the URL from exception object.